# Selenium + Python: finding elements by xpath with a loop

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm writing a testcase about moving markers on multiple sliders. I've done it with behave, but I call every slider and every marker on it without using a loop, like this one: https://github.com/Ketochka/Selenium_Behave_tests/blob/master/steps/Selenium_slider_dance.py
It works, but I want code to be shorter.

I try to use it this way(below), but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help with how to find array of elements with a loop?

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Slider_Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_sortable_elements(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical")
        frame_ = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
        driver.switch_to_frame(frame_)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        eq_current = []
        eq_marker = []
        for i in range(1,8):
            eq_current[i] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='eq']/span["+str(i)+"]/div")
            eq_marker[i] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='eq']/span["+str(i)+"]/span")
            time.sleep(.1)
            print(eq_current[i].size['height'])

        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Slider_Test)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxKq4HdrUqSkOEtxRzJXTkNiQzQ

Comment: You might want to add what is not working? Any errors or exception?

Comment: Yes, sure: E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sortable_elements (__main__.Slider_Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-38665d5cbd26>", line 20, in test_sortable_elements
    eq_current[i] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='eq']/span["+str(i)+"]/div")
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 9.506s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: and  just the same if you decrease the range, e.g: `code`for i in range(1,5):`code`
But you see, there are 7 spans there: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxKq4HdrUqSkOEtxRzJXTkNiQzQ